# Label not properly implemented in UITableView, why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a tableView which should be populated with an `NSMutableArray`. This worked fine without a custom prototype `UITableViewCell`. I have an own file for the cell, named `SimpleTableCell`. The prototype cell in my storyboard has this class assigned to it. Contents of 
**SimpleTableCell.h:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SimpleTableCell : UITableViewCell
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *nameLabel;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *moreInfoLabel;
@end
```

This is imported to the `viewController` where I have the `tableView`, like this:
**CargoViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "StartupViewController.h"
#import "boatInfoViewController.h"
#import "SimpleTableCell.h"

@interface CargoViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource>

@property(strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *testLabel; //label I use to test stuff instead of LOG
@property(strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *findOwner; //button to summon pickerWheel
@property(strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *findShip; //Button to confirm selection in picker and unhide tableView
@property(strong,nonatomic) NSArray *boatOwners; //Array for boat owners.
@property(strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *boatsForOwner; //array for boats, added by owner
@property(strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *boatsTableView; //Table view
-(IBAction)findOwnerButtonPressed:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)findShipButtonPressed:(id)sender;
@property(strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *shipOwners; //ship owner picker wheel
@property(strong,nonatomic)IBOutlet UILabel *infoLabel;
/*@property(strong,nonatomic)IBOutlet UILabel *nameLabel; //These was tested, but didn't work. Illegal assignment error.
@property(strong,nonatomic)IBOutlet UILabel *moreInfoLabel;
@property(strong,nonatomic)IBOutlet UITableViewCell *SimpleTableCell;*/

@end
```

This, again, controls to the 
**CargoViewController.m** (Only relevant parts added)

```
#import "CargoViewController.h"
#import "SimpleTableCell.h"
@interface CargoViewController ()


@end

@implementation CargoViewController
@synthesize testLabel, findOwner, findShip,shipOwners, boatsTableView, infoLabel;
@synthesize boatOwners, boatsForOwner;

//When I try to synthesize name and infolabel in cell here, it does not work

//...more code...

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [boatsForOwner count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[SimpleTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}

cell.nameLabel.text = [boatsForOwner objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;
}
```

My problem is: 
`cell.nameLabel.text` is not found on object `UITableViewCell`
Which, according to [image] my storyboard is wrong(?)

For further information, the table worked before I implemented prototype cells. Before I just used defaults.
Error trigger:

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark PickerView DataSource

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:
(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
return [boatOwners count];
}
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
         titleForRow:(NSInteger)row
        forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
return [boatOwners objectAtIndex:row];
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark PickerView Delegate
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row
  inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
NSString *boatsFromOwner = [boatOwners objectAtIndex:[shipOwners selectedRowInComponent:0]];
//if(boatsForOwner) {[boatsForOwner release]; boatsForOwner = nil;}
boatsForOwner = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
if ([boatsFromOwner isEqualToString:@"Owner1"]) {
    [self.boatsForOwner addObject:@"Titanic1"];
    [self.boatsForOwner addObject:@"Titanic2"];
    [self.boatsForOwner addObject:@"Titanic3"];
    [self.boatsForOwner addObject:@"Titanic4"];
    [self.boatsForOwner addObject:@"Titanic5"];
    [self.boatsForOwner addObject:@"Titanic6"];
    [self.boatsForOwner addObject:@"Titanic7"];

}
NSLog(@"%@",boatsFromOwner);

[boatsTableView reloadData];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this line:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
```

for this:

```
SimpleTableCell *cell = (SimpleTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
```

and by the way, when using storyboard `tableView:dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` will never return `nil`.

Comment: If it never returns `nil`how should I Implement the cell instead?

Comment: + When I did as you said, this 
`LNG[44650:c07] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2372/UITableView.m:5471
LNG[44650:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'`happened. Fix?

Comment: you don't have to worry about the instantiation, iOS will do this for you

Comment: I miss the typecast in my previous answer, try it now including it

Comment: I still get this error. I select the contents of the array with the code i added at the bottom of my original post, and thats when the crash happens. Do you know why? (Talking about error i typed two comments ago)

Comment: I think that your array is Ok, can you check that the value of `simpleTableIdentifier` coincide with the Identifier in the storyboard?

Comment: Should not conflict, as the error died when i re-enabled `if (cell == nil) {cell = [[SimpleTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];}`
Now, tho, the table returns empty. Any idea why this happens? Fix? It still returns the correct amount of cells in the view, so the error might be in how i display data.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22577/discussion-between-tkanzakic-and-oscar-apeland)

Answer (score 0):

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
```

try change to

```
SimpleTableCell *cell = (SimpleTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
```